# google apps script deploy webpage from another domain access

Tags: google-apps-script

I have write script and I deploy it by my email which is @gmail.com and it was working very very well and others can see it by giving them permission to access and use it, but when The client makes a copy of this script with his email which is not @gmail.com he uses anther domain I can't open it and it tells me  that "Sorry, the file you have requested does not exist.Please check the address and try again."  and other users have same domain like client have same problem too

Soo what I got to do to let them see the deployed webpage by his email at his domain which is not google domain

If anyone can help please....

Comment: To clarify - you can't open a file that your client created? Is the project properly shared (button on top right)?

Comment: Are you saving the script on google sites, drive or spreadsheet?

Comment: the script saved in google spreadsheet

Comment: the spreadsheet is not for public it's for selected users giving them edit permission, although that users has permission couldn't see it although they have same domain like client

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the domain permissions by accessing the domain control panel.
The URL is [Google Domain Admin Panel](http://admin.google.com).
If you are saving the scripts on drive then change drive settings, otherwise change sites settings and so one.